# Move Document Library PowerShell

Tags: 2013, document-library, powershell, sharepoint-server

I am facing problems while trying to move a Document Library from one Subsite to another on a SharePoint 2013 on premise installation.

I want to "move" a document library with powershell from one subsite to another and I also want to keep the Version history of all files.

I found the following script:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Copy-all-SharePoint-Files-0999c53f

But the skript only copies the files and so they get a new version history. 
Is there a way to copy the history of each file too?

best regards
Alex

Comment: Have you tried using `Export/Import-SPWeb "http://sharepointurl/subsite1" -ItemUrl "lists/MyList" -Path "C:\"  -IncludeVersions All -IncludeUserSecurity"` ? -IncludeVersions should keep all versions of files, and IncludeUserSecurity keep permissions on list/files

Comment: If that solved your problem, please tell me so I would expand my comment as an answer, or you can do it yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please verify that you're using the `Export-SPWeb` and `Import-SPWeb` PowerShell cmdlets, with these arguments:

`-IncludeVersions All` : To keep all files verions
`-IncludeUserSecurity` : To keep permissions on files

Example :

```
Import-SPWeb "http://sharepointurl/subsite1" -ItemUrl "lists/MyList" -Path "C:\"  -IncludeVersions All -IncludeUserSecurity
```

Please replace "*sharepointurl/subsite1*" by your site url, and "*lists/MyList*" by your list url.

More informations on these cmdlet on technet : [Export-SPWeb](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ff607895%28v=office.15%29.aspx) / [Import-SPWeb](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ff607613(v=office.15).aspx)